# How can I set the value of a DropDownList using jQuery with having part of value

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have dropdown with values like `IN-91`,`US-1`,How can I set the dropdown value to `IN-91` with available response value `IN`

This wont work since it doesn't match my list of values

```
$("select#myID option[value='"+myresponse+"']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: your question is not clear; could you please set up a fiddle or describe in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#myID option[value^="in"]')    // option where the value begins with "in"
    .prop("selected", true)        // select the last element in the matched list
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wdv2t/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var val="IN";  //example
$("select#myID").find(":contains('"+val+"')").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/j2c4H/67/)

Comment: thanks for answer but what does value mean in question is value within option tag not the text(FYI)

Comment: @HardikBhalani Updated my answer.Now please check once. where val is your response.Check the demo also :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
$("select#myID").val(myresponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

`$("select#myID option:contains(" + myresponse + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');`